# Google Charts (Geochart) toggle region between World and Europe

Tags: php, javascript, google-visualization

is there a way to set a toggle option on the chart to switch the region between `World` and `Europe`

I googled like crazy and cant find anything. I know how to set the region just not toggle it.

Thanks
C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at this: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

In the middle, you can see an example where they are zoomed on Italia and the surroundings. This could help you.

Use this for Europe:

```
var options = { region: '150' }
```

Just skip the Region parameter for the world.

You could use a [toggle button](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) from JQuery to call the function.

Comment: So there is google charts no build in way to toggle the region setting?

Comment: No, but you can put the code in 2 functions. One for the world and one for Europe. Then call the function to generate the chart you want, from a button.

Comment: New link to documentation is https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?hl=en#Continent_Hierarchy